# Spring cloud Feign:no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView]

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I have a service which has a url that return ModelAndView Object. 
[image]

In its own point, I can access the website. But when I use spring cloud feign to invoke that url, it comes out that no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView] and contentType text/html. Here is my feign client. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change `empList()` method in your `ConsumerController` class like below.

```
public String empList() {
    return empService.empList();
}
```

`ModelAndView` is not the actual response of `/emplist` from `EmpController`. It will be handled by DispatchServlet and ViewResolver will resolve the actual view with your view name - `emp`. So, from the view of `ConsumerController`, The response will be `String` object.

Anyway, I'm not sure that it's a good idea that accessing another web page via feign client in your case. Because if the original html page contains additional resources like images that existing in your origin server, it will not be served.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think that Feign client can only accept Restful response, such as json, xml. response such as ModelAndView could not be resolved by spring feign.